# Water quality and its contribution to off-flavors

Tags: water, chemistry

I have a copy of my city water quality report in hand and, with no particular reason other to than to understand how water quality can affect the *taste* of beer, would like to know where I can find information describing common off-flavors and the root cause a component of the source water might have had in their production as well as acceptable ranges or limits thereof?

Comment: FWIW, This subject was complicated enough to push me into brewing with all Reverse Osmosis water and adding back minerals from that base. There's no "simple" chart or table for water chemistry management. Plus, some municipalities publish averages in their report, and there can be very high fluctuations in the water on a day to day basis if they have to route water differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Martin Brungard's excellent water spreadsheet (free at sites.google.com/site/brunwater/) not only will help you calculate what type of water you need for a particular beer, it also has a great section on water in general that should answer many of your questions.  Your city water report may not give you all the info you need.  For a complete analysis that includes all the info you need to have, go to www.wardlab.com and get test W-6 for about $16.50.

Answer (score 0):

Palmer has some good information in How to Brew. [Here is a link](http://www.howtobrew.com/section3/chapter15-1.html) to the 'free' edition.